# How to move Office 365 Outlook calendar to secondary monitor

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, multiple-monitors, calendar, office365

I am running Windows 7 and Office 365. In Outlook, I want to have my e-mail open on my primary screen and at the same time have my calendar on my secondary monitor. Ultimately I would like to have a shared calendar on this second monitor.

Is this possible?

Comment: You would have to write a Outlook add-on that opens the Calendar in its own Window.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on calendar menu button and select open in a new window. When the window pops up you can drag it onto a second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't have two instances using the web-based outlook. What you could do (if it's allowed by your particular outlook provider) is look for the IMAP/SMTP settings of your outlook 365 portal and configure it in outlook. If you are able to do so, you can run two individual instances of outlook outside of the browser - one calendar, one email.

Something like this should be visible on the options page of your outlook web portal.

[image: imap/smtp settings]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the calendar icon at the bottom left and select open in new window.